# To have lombok @Value, @NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor together

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

I am using lombok annotations on a class:

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

}
```

I need @Value as I want fields to be immutable, and constructor annotations as ORM framework I am using needs both a no arg constructor as well as constructor for initializing fields.

But IntelliJ marks this as error stating fields need to be initialized, while we have a noarg constructor defined by lombok.

How to work around this issue?

Comment: You cannot have a value class with final fields with a no-args constructor, because you cannot set the fields then.

Comment: You can set them by reflection or more reasonably inside the no-args constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@Value`, the lombok mark all fields as `final`, without default values, the `@NoArgsConstructor` will result in fields never initialized, that's why the IntelliJ complains.

You can config the lombok with

```
lombok.noArgsConstructor.extraPrivate=true
```

As a result, the `@NoArgsConstructor` will generate contractor with default values. The default value can be set with `@FieldDefaults`.

See documents:
[@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value)
[@FieldDefaults](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldDefaults)

Comment: Is is also possible to use @NoArgsConstructor(force = true), which "initializes all final fields to 0 / null / false"

Comment: cool +1. can you provide the full pojo with `@Value` and `@NoArgsConstructor` and the other config you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define the no-args constructor with the default values you want?

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

    TestClass() {
        x = "";
        y = "";
        z = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't ever assign empty string unless you have no other choice.